# How to see whats beyond the video sequence editor

Tags: video-sequence-editor

[image]

Is there anyway to see movie strips outside of the video sequence viewer? The image on the left side is my normal view. The picture on the right would be an extended view. Basically I have rolling pictures on the bottom and they come on and off the screen right from left. How do I see their position when they are not in the viewer. Its important for the timing of scrolling that happens for each image.

Answer (score 2):

You may choose to do some of the scrolling in the 3D View first to produce an image sequence, then  later used in the Blender Video Sequence Editor, VSE.  The 3D View can show objects not in the camera.

As another example if a Blender User wanted to have fancy 3D titling that would be created in the 3D View first as an image sequence first.  Simple titling is available in the VSE.

By using planes with a texture and a camera with orthogonal settings you camera will behave more like the VSE.  The texture is the movie or image sequence that has already been created.

I tend to have two scenes.  SceneA, 3D View and Post processing No VSE.  SceneB, VSE only.

Comment: Thank you with your thoughts. I am going to play around with those ideas. But maybe the creators of blender could add that in the future. I adjusted my workflow and understand key frames to perfect the timing.